# find attribute value using closest function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried this but didn't know whats wrong with it. Results undefined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function(event) {
    var test = $(this).parent('.parentClass').closest('.headingLink').attr('href');
    console.log("testing this", test);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  <div class="link__img">
    <img alt="ffdbb" class="article-link__imgSrc" src="img.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="headingLink" target="jakfhaf" alt="somethingf" href="www.google.com">
      <h4>some head</h4>
    </a>
    <p>hdgajsfjghasjfh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` traverse up the DOM tree. What you are looking for is `.find()`. Also you are using `.parent()` which traverses up one level. Use `.closest()` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function(event) {
    var test = $(this).closest('.parentClass').find('.headingLink').attr('href');
    console.log("testing this", test);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  <div class="link__img">
    <img alt="ffdbb" class="article-link__imgSrc" src="img.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="headingLink" target="jakfhaf" alt="somethingf" href="www.google.com">
      <h4>some head</h4>
    </a>
    <p>hdgajsfjghasjfh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead of `parent` and use [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the child.

`.parents()` - Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

`.find()` - Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function(event) {
    var test = $(this).parents('.parentClass').find('.headingLink').attr('href');
    console.log("testing this", test);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  <div class="link__img">
    <img alt="ffdbb" class="article-link__imgSrc" src="img.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="headingLink" target="jakfhaf" alt="somethingf" href="www.google.com">
      <h4>some head</h4>
    </a>
    <p>hdgajsfjghasjfh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is just for searching in parents not in childrens. You're searching in childrens so use `find()` instead of `closest()`.

Answer (score 0):

`parent([selector])` only traverses up one level, and `closest(selector)` only traverses up. Instead, I think you should use `closest('.parentClass')` and then use `closestParentClass.find('.headingLink')`.

Edit: @Kalimah has a more detailed (with code) explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function(event) {
    var test = $(this).closest('.parentClass').find('.headingLink').attr('href');
    console.log("testing this ", test);
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  <div class="link__img">
    <img alt="ffdbb" class="article-link__imgSrc" src="img.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a class="headingLink" target="jakfhaf" alt="somethingf" href="www.google.com">
      <h4>some head</h4>
    </a>
    <p>hdgajsfjghasjfh</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `.closest` and `.find` selectors are complements of each other and
>   used together are the best way to get to the corresponding element of
>   where the click (or any event) occurred.
>
> The `.closest` selector traverses up the DOM to find the parent that
>   matches the conditions where as the `.find` selector traverses down
>   the DOM where the event occurred, that matches the conditions.

`var test = $(this).closest('.parentClass').find('.headingLink').attr('href');`

Replacing your code with this line of code should work for your problem.